# I want to identify encoding of these videos

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, urlencode, non-ascii-characters

I have a bunch of videos I downloaded 20 years ago now. The website I believe had them in Japanese. My PC at the time didn't understand unicode characters and I downloaded them with Download Accelerator Plus I believe! So all of the video titles look like a mixture of broken ASCII and URLEncoded characters

Is there any way to get these titles back? Here are some samples:

16. %ec†%a1%ecŠ%b9%ec„%a0.avi
17. %ea%b0•%ec%a2…%ea%b5%ac, %ec†%ec%a3%bc%ed™˜.avi
18. %ea%b5%ac%ec%a2…%eb%a7Œ.avi
19. %ecœ%a4%ec%b0%bd%ec%bc.avi
20. %ea%b6Œ%eb%af%bc%ec%a3%bc (%e2˜…%e2˜…).avi

I dont remember the url, so I cannot check web archives

Any input welcome.

Thank you

Comment: Looks like Korean (some  Hangul Syllables) 16 송승섚
17 강종구, 솠주환
18 구종만
19 윤창켝  | 윤창켞 | 윤창켠
20 권민주 (★★)

Comment: oh great!! Yes Korean!! How did you translate it all? I put it into a Hangul converter but it looks encoded also... I have about 1000 videos I need to get through! Thanks!

Comment: I've figured it out now, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*How did you translate it all?*

First, suppose [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description) as `0xec`, `0xed` or `0xea` are first bytes of three-byte UTF-8 sequences; then

- convert every URL-encoded character to its byte value (e.g. `%a1` to `0xa1`), and
- take ANSI 1252 byte values of every literal character e.g. `†Š•…™˜Œœ,()`.

Then you have UTF-8 byte sequence for whole string and you can decode it simply.

**Exceptions**:

- missing character in string #17 (two-char string `%ec†` should be converted to a three-byte sequence, added `0x81`);
- the same in string #19 (two-char string `%ec%bc` should be converted to a three-byte sequence).

**Example** (manual conversion, exceptions indicated by `↑↑↑↑` in the following byte sequences, added `0x81`):

```
16 0xec,134,0xa1,0xec,138,0xb9,0xec,132,0xa0
송승선
17 0xea,0xb0,149,0xec,0xa2,133,0xea,0xb5,0xac,0x2c,0x20,0xec,134,0x81,0xec,0xa3,0xbc,0xed,153,152
강종구, 솁주환                                                    ↑↑↑↑
18 0xea,0xb5,0xac,0xec,0xa2,133,0xeb,0xa7,140
구종만
19 0xec,156,0xa4,0xec,0xb0,0xbd,0xec,0xbc,0x81
윤창켁                                     ↑↑↑↑   
20 0xea,0xb6,140,0xeb,0xaf,0xbc,0xec,0xa3,0xbc,0x20,0x28,0xe2,152,133,0xe2,152,133,0x29
권민주 (★★)
```

**Google translate**:

[image: detected Korean]

Comment: Thank you for clarifying and the explanation. As I commented above, I did it now. I just kinda freestyled it. I converted the special chars to their HEX equivalent then added a percentage to them. Then I URLDecoded the whole lot afterwards. It sounds like you explained what I did a bit better than I understood it :) I just wrote a small program in C# to loop through them and apply the changes. Encoding and such isnt my strong suit but im glad it was identified as Korean!